# is mysql password update dependent on the user account on linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, unix

Hi Mysql and Linux gurus!

I have run into a weird behavior issue with Mysql server install on my local machine. Here is the history -

- I normally operate as a `non root` user, and use `su` to get root priviledges for installs.
- I installed `MySQL 5.1 server` on my `Fedora Linux machine 13`
- I made it necessary for **MySQLs** `root` user to have a password when connecting using the mysql client from `localhost`
- **This is what i need** - I need to test a shell script which calls the `mysql` client **without username and password**, I need to remove the password for `mysqls` root user. **Also (importantly)**, the script should run from the `root` user of my computer.

  mysql -D dbname < script.sql
- **This is what i did** - From my **non-root** linux account i started mysql client, logged in as root@localhost, and ran the following command to remove the root@localhost password

  `update user set password = PASSWORD('') where user = 'root' and host = 'localhost';`
- **The issue!** - Now from my **non-root** unix account when i run just `mysql` it successfully logs me in. (so far so good). **But** when i do  `su`, login as **linux root** (super user) and run `mysql` - I get

  `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

**Post Script** - I have logged in with an alternate account from the super user account and re-run the query to update the user, It still didn't work. How come I can run `mysql` client without username and password as a **non-root user**, but cannot do the same as a linux super user???

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: what happens if you use an empty password, instead of no pasword? (so use `mysql -p` instead of `mysql` ? I think that you have set your apssword to '', which is probably something not-empty when hashed with `password`

Comment: When you 'just run mysql', is there a .my.cnf for the non-root user? Try `mysql -u root` both as non-root and root, both should work. Did you `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after updating the password?

Comment: @Nanne - still get the same error as a superuser.

Comment: @Konerak - No I didn't, and that worked! Thanks. Do put that in an answer so that I can select it as one.

Comment: glad it helped. I considered it too common an error to put as an answer, but if it actually was the answer, I guess it should be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating GRANTS or the mysql tables directly, many people forget to execute `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`.

Only after `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`, changes take effect.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL accounts are completely independent from system accounts. They may coincidentally have the same usernames (like the default `root` account being the system AND mysql super-user accounts).

Once you've set a password on an account in mysql, you have to force the mysql monitor (`mysql` command) to prompt for a password (`-p`) option, and possibly specify your MySQL username (`-u` option) if your MySQL account name doesn't match your Linux username:

In other words:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

will tell MySQl to try and log you into the mysql `root` account, and to prompt for the account's password.